Complex exponential Fourier coefficients of a convolution involving the exponetial function
In the book "Elementary Classical Analysis", by Marsden, the following is proposed as a worked example:

Let $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R},g:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ and extend by periodicity. Define the convolution of $f$ and $g$ by $$(f*g)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(y)g(x-y)dy.$$ Compute the Fourier series of $f*g$ in terms of that of $f$ and $g$, using the exponential form of Fourier series.

In the presented solution it is shown that $c_n=2\pi a_nb_n$, where $c_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of the convolution and $a_n,b_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$ and $g$, respectively.
It can also be shown that for a function $f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$ with Fourier coefficients $a_n$ and a given constant $\alpha$, the Fourier coefficients of $\alpha f$ are $\alpha a_n$.
Now, let's consider the case where $f$ and $g$ are both the exponential function, that is, $f(x)=g(x)=e^x$. The Fourier coefficients of $f$ (and $g$) are $a_n=b_n=\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi(1-ni)}$. So, by the previous theorem (or example) we get that the Fourier coefficients of $f*g$ are $c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{1-ni}\right)^2$.
However, if we compute the convolution we get that
$$
(f*g)(x)=\int_0^{2\pi}e^ye^{x-y}dy=\int_0^{2\pi}e^xdy=2\pi e^x,
$$
from where using the second result we get that $c_n=\frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{1-ni}$.
These two sets of coefficients are clearly different, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Try computing $f*g$ again but using $$ g(x) = f(x) = e^{x \text{ mod } 2\pi}.$$ In the convolution you have to be careful with the "extending periodically" part. You cannot just write $e^ye^{x-y} = e^x$. These functions are supposed to be $2\pi$ periodic.
